# CRUD java code error

Tags: java, netbeans

i have a problem with the following code and i've been struggling with it for over a week now.  i'm sure it's a basic problem but i can't get anywhere with it..

i'm trying to create a very simple CRUD application that allows me to keep a list of assets.  the code i'm struggling with is as follows;

```
private void displayResult(List resultList) {
    ArrayList<String> tableHeaders = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList tableData = new ArrayList();
    tableHeaders.add("AssetNo"); 
    tableHeaders.add("Type");
    tableHeaders.add("SubType");
    tableHeaders.add("Supplier");

    for(Object o : resultList) {
        Asset asset = (Asset)o;
        ArrayList<Object> oneRow = new ArrayList<Object>();
        oneRow.add(asset.getAssetNo());
        oneRow.add(asset.getType());
        oneRow.add(asset.getSubType());
        oneRow.add(asset.getSupplier());
        tableData.add(oneRow);
    }

    jTable1.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(tableData, tableHeaders));
}
```

Netbeans 7.3 displays an error on the for(Object.. line and the jTable1.setMode1.. lines.

Could anyone point me in the right direction to fix these problems?

Thanks

Comment: Can you lease also tell us which error s displayed?

Comment: on for statement Netbeans states 'for-each not applicable to expression type  required: array or java.lang.iterable found: List

Comment: onthe jTable1 it states 'no suitable constructor found for DefaultTableModel(ArrayList,ArrayList<String>)

Answer (score 5):

The [`DefaultTableModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html) constructor takes [`Vector`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html)s, not `List`s.

As for the `for`-loop error, I bet you imported `java.awt.List` instead of `java.util.List`.

Comment: Thanks, i 'fixed imports' about 50 times but it didn't 'fix them'.. changing awt for util removed the error from the for loop! many thanks .  I'm confused about the Vector.  where do I change it to a list?

Comment: @user2471152 Try using a `Vector` instead of a list.